# How to compare my result data to all data from firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, compare, ocr

i have a result from ocr like "vegetable oil, potatoes, etc" and i also have multiple data from firebase such as vagetable oil = 'halal'. I want to compare my ocr result to knowing wheter my ocr result is halal or not based on my data inside my firebase

> [This is the result of OCR with google vision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiBee.jpg)
>
> [This is my data that I want to compare with the results of the OCR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spGVJ.jpg)

This is code for the result of OCR :

```
//get drawable bitmap buat ocr
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable)mPreviewIv.getDrawable();
Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();

TextRecognizer recognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(getApplicationContext()).build();

if (!recognizer.isOperational()){
    Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else{
    Frame frame = new Frame.Builder().setBitmap(bitmap).build();
    SparseArray<TextBlock> items = recognizer.detect(frame);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();


    for ( int i = 0; i<items.size(); i++){
        TextBlock myItem = items.valueAt(i);
        sb.append(myItem.getValue());
        sb.append("\n");

    }
    mResultEt.setText(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i mean how to Compare Myresult data to all data from firebase,

Comment: Can you please explain little bit, not understandable code. You can get all data data from firebase then in loop check or match the strings.

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni example , i have a result from ocr like "vegetable oil, potatoes, etc" and i also have multiple data from firebase such as vagetable oli = 'halal'. I want to compare my ocr result to knowing wheter my ocr result is halal or not based on my data inside my firebase

Comment: Then Need to do one thing let suppose you get potatoes, Now get all data from firebase and on particular field match your string, if its true store that value in temp. So after completing to compare with all data you will get result in temp. If temp is null then no data is matched

Comment: @MayurCoceptioni do i have to use for loop or there is another way to match my data to a particular field ? thanks in advance

Comment: No there is no another way because in firebase we can't use where condition